# How to transition smoothly from AddForce() to MovePosition() in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a character that dashes using AddForce(), after dashing, i want him to auto walk in set speed using MoovePosition().

This project was made using the 3D engine and it work flawlessly. But I've changed it to 2D and after the AddForce, the character abruptly changes to the speed that MovePosition() set, it looks bad.

I thought about checking the velocity after the dash and when it reaches the same velocity as when auto-walk is happening, it calls for MovePosition. But it doesn't seem a good approach.. I'd love to receive some tips on this issue.

```
      if(moveFactor!= 0)
    {
        Vector2 appliedForce = transform.position + transform.up * moveFactor;
        Debug.Log("appliedForce: " + appliedForce.magnitude);
        playerRigidbody.AddForce(appliedForce);
        autoWalk = true;
        moveFactor = 0;
    }

    if (autoWalk) playerRigidbody.MovePosition(walkForce);
```

moveFactor is a float value that a swipe detector script returns. The code is in FixedUpdate as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to see the problem instead of trying to reconstruct the picture from your description, but I'll try my best.

## The Problem

The same frame you start the dash, you set `autoWalk` to `true`. As soon as the `if` statement is exited, the `if (autoWalk)` is evaluated and you start manually moving the `RigidBody` using `MovePosition()` — before the force has even been added.

I'm not sure why that ever worked in 3D, though.

## Solution #1

Instead of using `MovePosition()`, move with `AddForce()`, with the default `ForceMode2D`; or with `playerRigidbody.velocity`, where-in you set it once, not every frame.

## Solution #2

Instead of using `AddForce()`, for the dash, use the same old `MovePosition()` you use inside `if (autoWalk)`.

Just increase the magnitude of `walkForce` several times for the duration of the dash.

## Solution #3

The problem with using `AddForce()` for it is that you don't know when it's "finished", so you don't know when to transition to `MovePosition()`.

If the above solutions don't work for you, implement the dash manually. You can do this with [`Vector2.Lerp()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Lerp.html) (or [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)) inside a [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).

```
if (moveFactor != 0)
{
    Vector2 endPosition = transform.position + transform.up * moveFactor;
    StartCoroutine(Dash(endPosition));
    moveFactor = 0;
}
```

Where `Dash()` is:

```
public float dashDuration = 1f;

private IEnumerator Dash(Vector2 endPosition)
{
    autoWalk = false;

    // Record the original position before you begin moving the object.
    float startingPosition = transform.position;
    float elapsed = 0f;

    while (elapsed < dashDuration )
    {
        elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        Vector2 nextPosition = Vector2.Lerp(startingPosition, endPosition, elapsed / dashDuration );
        playerRigidbody.MovePosition(nextPosition);
        // Note: if the RigidBody is kinematic (isKinematic == true), this will simply teleport it to the given position.
        // Otherwise, it will comply with its interpolation settings.
        // You could directly modify playerRigidbody.position or transform.position (though the former is faster) for the same teleportation.
        yield return null;
    }

    autoWalk = true;
}
```

`appliedForce` might not immediately work as `endPosition` — modify it so it does, in that case. `dashDuration` is in seconds.

**Make sure Dash() is started only *once*, until it is finished. You can do this by saving the `Coroutine` returned by `StartCoroutine()` in a private field member and comparing it to null before you start, but you shouldn't have to. If the code inside the `if (moveFactor != 0)` statement is executed something like every frame, change your code accordingly.**

I've not tested this, so I'm not sure it will check for collisions. If it doesn't but you need it to, you can add that funcionality by raycasting (or box-casting, sphere-casting, or whatever kind of `Collider` you use):

```
private IEnumerator Dash(Vector2 endPosition)
{
    float startingPosition = transform.position;
    float elapsed = 0f;

    while (elapsed < dashDuration )
    {
        elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        Vector2 nextPosition = Vector2.Lerp(startingPosition, endPosition, elapsed / dashDuration );
        // Add the raycast here and only execute the MovePosition() if the returned RaycastHit2D's collider property is null.
        // (The raycast's should extend to nextPosition.)
        playerRigidbody.MovePosition(nextPosition);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Using MovePosition() in place of of AddForce() solved the issue, it's not the perfect fluid motion that AddForce() has, but it's still pretty good.

Comment: You can increase/decrease the magnitude gradually instead of changing it immediately for a smoother effect. And if this solved your issue, don't forget to accept the answer.